# background-image not working(converting not local to local)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, path, background

The Code:

```
style="background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg);"
```

Image is visible when doing this, but thats the whole reason im asking this question.

```
style="background-image: url(http://foo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg);"
```

wp-content IS the first folder in the path.

I've tried:

```
style="background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg');"

style="background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg);"

style="background-image: url('../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg');"
```

So the question is, why isn't the image not showing when the path is correct?

Solution Implementation:

```
style="background-image: url(insert_your_localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg);"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call image URL with site URL functions like [wp_upload_dir](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/), [site_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url), [content_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/content_url)
**Veysel Xankisiyev** have already submitted the solution.

Based on your examples, I'm trying to explain whats wrong with each method you're tried.

```
url('wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg')
```

In this case, browser will treat this image URL relative to your current URL. If you are on the home page, consider example.com, the resultant image URL will be `example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg`.
This will work as long as you were one home page, consider if you are in some other pages example.com/about/, the resultant image URL will be `example.com/about/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg`. it is wrong one.

```
background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg);
```

In this case, it will treat url relative to the domain/host always. Even if you are one homepage or in other pages, the resultant image url will be 
`example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg`.
But as you said it didn't worked in your case means, your WordPress url path will be something like `localhost/wordpress/` or `example.com/wordpress` or so. In such case, the resultant image URL will be `localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg` , wrong one.

Comment: Veysels Answer didn't work, but this answered some questions I was confused about.

Answer (score 1):

The path isn't correct.

Try this:

```
style="background-image: url('../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/example.jpg');"
```

Comment: I forgot to add i tried that too, 5 seconds before you added that question, my bad.